# Go Global Variables and Scopes of slices

Tags: go

I am starting out with GO language, and getting an error I cannot figure out.  How do I create a global slice that all functions within the module can use?  Here is what I have:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Req struct {
    Req     int
    Name    string
}

var Reqs []Req

func ReadReqs(fp string) {
    var CReq Req;
    CReq.Req = 1
    CReq.Name = "first"
    Reqs := append(Reqs, CReq)
}

func main() {
    Reqs := make([]Req, 0)

    if len(Reqs) > 0 {
        fmt.Println(Reqs[0])
    }

    fmt.Println(Reqs)
}
```

This code will not compile because of the following error:

```
./question.go:18: Reqs declared and not used
```

I was thinking that declaring var Reqs []Req should declare the variable, but it does not seem to be aware of it inside the ReadReqs function.  I do realize that globals are BAD but I would like to use global var for this simple program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay first of all I'd recommend you to read [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) before continuing.

You are declaring your global variable using:

```
var Reqs []Req
```

Then re-declaring a variable with the same name using:

```
Reqs := ......
```

You are declaring two different variables.

---

var Name type also initializes the variable:

```
var s string
```

Is equivalent to:

```
s := ""
```

So this makes the following line useless:

```
Reqs = make([]Req, 0)
```

---

You can try your fixed code [here](http://play.golang.org/p/9tHAm_zm0L) (Golang Play).

Answer (score 2):

With `:=` you are declaring a new variable (not writing to the global) and that new variable at function scope is unused. (Has nothing to do with globals.)

Answer (score 1):

You're re-declaring `Reqs` with the `:=` operator. Drop the colon.

You should probably start with the basics first:

- [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/)
- [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)
- [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)

Comment: Thank you, I have started working with these documents, just could not figure out the cause